# How to return a color-value based a date and random?

Tags: php, arrays, date, colors

The designer came up with a rather weird idea or a color-wheel (with 36 colors).

**I need to write a function that is returning `one` color but based on the `date`.**

> **How the website should work**
>   Based on the current date (you see german dates on the image underneath) the site should have this background color.

So on "January 1st" the first color (blueviolet or what you might call that) should be the background of the frontpage. 10 days later the next color. So within one year all 36 colors should be looped through in the order of the wheel.

I guess untill that point an intermediate programmer could help me with this, I don't know how to do that.

[image]

**But it gets slightly more complicated**
The designer wants every page of the website to be in a different color also.
So imagine the site has like 10 pages (Home, About, Whatever, Gallery) every page should have one of the "closest" 10 colors.

*Wow, even I don't unterstand it when explainig it.*

So what I want to do is create a function that is returning a *random color* out of a *pool of 10 colors* that are based on the *current date*.

So on "January 1st" I want the following the colors to be pushed in an array and return one of those colors randomly.

```
function colorWheel($alpha) { // 36 colors
    $colors = array(
        rgba(170, 207, 172, 1),
        rgba(180, 211, 164, 1),
        rgba(189, 214, 145, 1),
        rgba(196, 217, 134, 1),
        rgba(206, 222, 124, 1),
        rgba(214, 226, 124, 1),
        rgba(226, 233, 124, 1),
        rgba(234, 235, 122, 1),
        rgba(236, 235, 120, 1),
        rgba(241, 231, 118, 1),
        rgba(240, 224, 118, 1),
        rgba(240, 216, 117, 1),
        rgba(237, 208, 115, 1),
        rgba(233, 199, 112, 1),
        rgba(230, 191, 110, 1),
        rgba(226, 177, 115, 1),
        rgba(221, 162, 110, 1),
        rgba(218, 153, 116, 1),
        rgba(215, 141, 112, 1),
        rgba(209, 140, 120, 1),
        rgba(203, 138, 119, 1),
        rgba(197, 136, 126, 1),
        rgba(191, 138, 134, 1),
        rgba(186, 142, 144, 1),
        rgba(181, 145, 157, 1),
        rgba(176, 151, 170, 1),
        rgba(170, 135, 178, 1),
        rgba(164, 159, 189, 1),
        rgba(166, 167, 194, 1),
        rgba(166, 177, 201, 1),
        rgba(166, 182, 204, 1),
        rgba(163, 186, 201, 1),
        rgba(164, 190, 196, 1),
        rgba(166, 196, 191, 1),
        rgba(167, 198, 185, 1),
        rgba(168, 201, 178, 1),
    );
}
```

Any idea how to do so?

Comment: Helping you with the first part will be easy. But the part you can not explain will be difficult :-) Do you mean that if Home page has colour `N` then About page should have colour `N+1`, Whatever `N+2` and so on?

Comment: Working on a solution, 10 minutes

Comment: you can use [array_rand](http://php.net/array_rand) to get random value from array.

Comment: @kmkaplan Actually yeah. However I guess that might be really tough since I'm based on wordpress and simply want to add the background-color as inline style to my `header.php` file. How should I find out which page is `N+1` … therefore I would have simply suggested to create a pool out of 10 colors and shuffle through them. So in January only "blueish" colors would occur on the page.

Comment: Another background color every day? Has your graphic designer ever heard of "corporate design" and why it shouldn't change daily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will have a one day shift every leap year but this should be ok for your needs.

```
function colorWheel($alpha, $shift = 0) { // 36 colors
    $time = time();
    $yearDay = $time % (60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
    $idx = $yearDay / 60 / 60 / 24 / 10;
    $colors = array(
        rgba(170, 207, 172, $alpha),
        …
        rgba(168, 201, 178, $alpha),
    );
    return $colors[($idx + $shift) % count($colors)];
}
```

I do not know much about Wordpress but to get the one color per page functionnality you should do a trick like:

```
$page_shift = array(
    '/about.html' => 1,
    '/whatever.html' => 2,
    '/gallery.html' => 3,
    …
);
$shift = $page_shift[$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']];
$color = colorWheel(1, $shift);
```

Comment: What is `$alpha` in your case? I thought it to be the `rgbA` value of each color. So when calling `colorWheel(.5)` I want `rgba(168, 201, 178, .5)` to be returned.

Comment: What is you're `$alpha` doing?

Comment: @matt I thought your `$alpha` was the parameter that would do the colour shifting for each different page. I edited to show how you would achieve a different colour on each page.

Comment: Thank, couldn't be more perfect! Wow.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php

// $colors contains what the designers you gave ...
$colors = array (
    array (0x0, 0x0, 0x0),
    // ...
    array (0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF),
);  

$number_of_colors = count($colors); // 36 in your example
$number_of_days_per_year = 365; // for brevity of the example

$day = intval(date('z'));

// some 'lower school math' magic :)
$index = round($day * $number_of_colors / $number_of_days_per_year);

// the color of the day is ..... 
$color = $colors[$index];
```

Comment: Why are you creating a table of colors? Just create them on the fly.

Comment: @ Mahmoud Al-Qudsi: I tried to keep things simple so that the answer itself can be understood. Some 'color math' may improve performance. But this is hypothetical.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is what I've came up with:

```
function colorWheel($time, $page) {
    // All possible RGB color values
    $colors = array(
        array(170, 207, 172, 1),
        // ...
    );

    $index = ($time % (60 * 60 * 24 * 365) / 60 / 60 / 24 / 10);

    return 'background-color: rgba(' . ($colors[($index) % count($colors)-1][0]) .
           ', ' . ($colors[($index) % count($colors)-1][1]) . ', ' . ($colors[($index) % count($colors)-1][2]) . ', ' .
           ($colors[($index) % count($colors)-1][3]) . ');';
}

// Usage: 
echo "<body style='" . colorWheel(time(), 'home') . "'>";
```

Though I haven't implemented the different-color-per-page functionality, tell me, is it possible to use a session, text file or DB to store what page has which color?

Comment: Yeah, that might of course be possible. I'm working with wordpress. The goal would be that in January the each page of the website has a different blueish color of the color-wheel.