# CSS or PHP? color that is 80% of original but without "transparency"?

Tags: php, css, colors

this might be a tough question.

I have a php function that returns a color value in `rgba()` with an argument `$alpha`.

```
function colorWheel($alpha) {

   "rgba(170, 135, 178, ".$alpha.")"
   …
}
```

So when calling …

```
.title { color: <?php echo colorWheel(.8); ?>; }
```

… I get `rgba(170, 135, 178, .8);`

---

The problem I have with this is that the color is "transparent" and shows "overlays".

[image]

**However what I really like to have is just 80% of the color value!** 
Without any transparent overlays.

The question is now how to solve this?

Any creative ideas how to do that? I don't need to use `rgba()` it's just the easiest thing that came to my mind. Is there a **CSS** way not to blend overlaying shapes that have an alpha value?

Or is there a php solution to calculate a the **80%** version of `rgb(170, 135, 178)`?
It is important that this calculation works dynamically with the function because there are more colors in the function - **this is a follow-up question to ["How to return a color-value based a date and random?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231823/how-to-return-a-color-value-based-a-date-and-random)!**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: But that's how transparent colors work. I think you want an overall `opacity: .8;` on the entire container for these objects instead of individual RGBA colors on each object.

Comment: Rather than using the alpha value to get an "80% of that colour" representation, why don't you convert to HSL and reduce luminosity or saturation of it, then convert back to RGB and use those values instead of amending the alpha value. RGBA works with alpha..

Comment: I know that is how transparency works :) That is why I'm asking. And unfortunately the items with those colors are not the same "container" but different objects which are overlaying each other. That's why I also asked for a php answer. I just thought maybe I missed some CSS setting.

Comment: 80% of what? Html the color spaces RBG and HSL. You can take 80% of all colorchannels or convert to hsl and reduce saturation or luminance to 80%.

Comment: @Christoph It doesn't matter what! I could also create the array with Hex-colors.  See this … http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231823/how-to-return-a-color-value-based-a-date-and-random … I just need the function to work like that. I simply want to pass along an `$alpha` argument and get the 80% version of the color in the `colorWheel()` returned. I don't care if I get a `rgba()`, `rgb()` or `#hex` returned. I just need to set the value with css.

Comment: @matt all i wanted to say is that there is a difference between calculating rgb 80% or using hsl and decreasing luminance to 80%. Take a look at my answer for further info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that should do it:

```
function colorWheel($alpha) {
    $r = round(170 * $alpha);
    $g = round(135 * $alpha);
    $b = round(178 * $alpha);
    "rgba($r, $g, $b, 1)";
    …
}
```

well, that makes the color darker, if you want to make it lighter you have to put alpha to a value > 1, and also check if r,g or b goes over 255 and set it to 255 if it does

Comment: actually you don't need rgba (which has lesser support) if you don't use the alpha channel.

Answer (score 1):

The Question is what your definition of "80% of the color" actually is.

CSS has 2 color spaces available at the moment: RGB and HSL (which is actually supported pretty [well](http://caniuse.com/#search=hsl)).

You could do the following RGB calculation:

```
function colorWheel($alpha) {

    'rgba('.$r*$alpha.','.$g*$alpha.','.$b*$alpha.', 1)';
    …
}
```

Or you could take HSL and just reduce the luminance (and or Saturation) channel by 20%. The HSL colorspace is more intuitive when doing things like making colors darker/brighter.

```
function colorWheel($alpha) {

    "hsla($h,$s,".$l*$alpha.",1)";
    // or
    // ("hsla($h, "+$s*$alpha+", $l, 1)";)
    …
}
```

These all yield (slightly) different results.

The colorspaces can be converted into each other via some not too complicated formulas. Perhaps you should take a look at a random colorpicker(e.g. [this one](http://www.workwithcolor.com/hsl-color-picker-01.htm) or [that one](http://www.colorpicker.com/)) and then decide, which way of calculation suits you best.

Comment: Does PHP actually interpolate `$r*$alpha` within a string? I haven't written PHP in forever.

Answer (score 0):

To simulate color with opacity you also need background color. Lets say, that `R,G,B` are background color components, and `r,g,b` are you color components.
If you want to simulate opacity color on specific background, you should take corresponding values of same canal and add them with specific weights:

```
r = r*alpha + R*(1-alpha)
g = g*alpha + G*(1-alpha)
b = b*alpha + B*(1-alpha)
```

Lets take simple example. You want to get `alpha = 0.8`  on color `rgb(r,g,b) = rgb(255,0,0)`  (red) on background `rgb(R,G,B) = rgb(255,255,255)` (white). That means, you need sum 80% your color + 20% BG:

```
r = 255*0.8 + 255*0.2 = 255
g = 0*0.8 + 255*0.2 = 51
b = 0*0.8 + 255*0.2 = 51
```

Comment: are you sure this is right? For me I get always a darker version. And not a lighter one.